# How to attach image from a list of predefined images?

Tags: 7, media, navigation

Anyone had this? I have a custom content type and I want to give an option to attach an image from a list of predefined images (in my case - a list of product series logotypes). The admin interface would be a simple dropdown of logotype labels:

```
- None -
Series 1
Series 2
Series 3
```

How would I then process the selection and convert it into a real image?
What would be the best practice here?

Regards,
Artur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are general guidelines as I made something like this but for D6.
I would create a logotype variable in [template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) and then loop on you dropdown variable. For each value selected I would add an `<img src='path/to/logo1.png' alt='Logo 1' />` to your logotypes variables.
Then just display the variable in you node template.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<?php
    $logotypes = array(
        'dropdown_key1' => '[path_to_image_1]',
        'dropdown_key2' => '[path_to_image_2]'
    );    

   print('<ul>');
   foreach ($element['#object']->field_logotypy['pl'] as $logo){
        print "<li>" . $logotypes[$logo["value"]] . "</li>";
   }
     print('</ul>');
?>
```

This is placed in field--field_name--content-type.tpl.php.
In the admin form, the editor selects a logotype name from a dropdown, which has predefined keys as in the $logotypes array. The values on the admin side will be the paths to actual logotype images.

What I don't like about the code is the hard-coded 'pl' language index used here. I assume though, that with some more reading I will be able to figure out how to address it better - the logotypes are actually not language-dependent.

HTH